# Hallar cantidad de números impares de una matriz en java

Tags: java

Tengo que resolver el siguiente ejercicio en java:

> La función mistery toma los siguientes parámetros:
>
> - Una matriz de enteros 2D llamada nums
> - Un número entero llamado filas que representa el número de filas en números
> - Un entero llamado cols que representa el número de columnas en nums
>
> NO debe asumir que las filas / columnas de nums están configuradas.
> Utilice los parámetros en su bucle for.
>
> El método mistery debe modificar los números de matriz originales
> dividiendo cada elemento por tres, redondeando hacia abajo (debido a
> la división de enteros). Luego debe contar el número de elementos
> impares en números (después de dividir por 3), luego devolver ese
> recuento.
>
> Puede completar esto usando uno o dos bucles for anidados; la elección
> es suya.
>
> Un algoritmo acumulador está involucrado de alguna manera, forma o
> forma en la solución.

Ya logre conseguir la nueva matriz después de dividir cada elemento entre 3, solo me falta hallar la cantidad de números impares que se generan en esta nueva matriz.

Aquí esta el código de lo que he hecho hasta ahora:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] a = {
            {14,20,3,2},
            {4,15,6,1},
            {12,31,4,16}
        };
        System.out.println(mystery(a,3,4)); //should print 5
        //prints array
        for(int[] row : a){
            for(int e : row){
                System.out.print(e + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public static int mystery(int[][] nums, int rows, int cols)
    {
        Integer resultOdd = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int sumOddRows;
        for (rows = 0; rows < nums.length; rows++){
            sumOddRows = 0;
            for (cols = 0; cols < nums[0].length; cols++){
                nums[rows][cols] = nums[rows][cols]/3;
                Integer x  = Integer.valueOf(nums[rows][cols]);
                if (x%2!=0){
                    sumOddRows += x;
                    count++;
                }
                resultOdd = sumOddRows;
            }
        }
        int sumTotalOdd = 0;
        sumTotalOdd += resultOdd;
    
        return sumTotalOdd;
    }
}
```

El resultado es este:
6
4 6 1 0
1 5 2 0
4 10 1 5

Comment: Te faltó agregar el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora

Comment: perdon es que se me olvido, y no se manejar la plataforma

Comment: [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/431103/edit) Y agrega tu código

Comment: no acabo de entender porque no te sale lo de cuantos numeros impares tiene la nueva matriz.. , si ya lo controlas con el count....

Comment: el codigo que hice

Comment: ya lo probe de nuevo, y me sale 6 en vez 5

Comment: Tienes que devolver count que es donde guardas la cantidad de impares

Answer (score 0):

Cuidado tienes muchos errores!!!mira lo que estas haciendo, estas pansando a la funcion dos parametros, la cantidad de "filas y columnas " totales, pero tu estos números los utilizas como indices del array, pero esto no es correcto... recuerda que los indices empìezan en el 0

array[0]
array[1]
......

fijate en esta linea

```
  nums[rows][cols] = nums[rows][cols]/3;
```

otra cosa que haces es que los parametros de entrada los utilizas como variables contador de los bucles,  que se modifican dentro de los bucles y luego los utilizas como indices de los arrays, los parametros de entrada de una funcion no los reutilices dentro del codigo como variables a no ser que sea imprescindible.

```
 for (a = 0; a < rows; a++){
        sumOddRows = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < cols; i++){
            nums[a][i] = nums[a][i]/3;
            Integer x  = Integer.valueOf(nums[a][i]);
            if (x%2!=0){
                sumOddRows += x;
                count++;
            }
            resultOdd = sumOddRows;
        }
    }
```